# orphan removal constraint violation

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, cascade, orphan

I am using EclipseLink and have the following entity classes (I tried to simplify the scenario as much as I could, but after any further simplification, the error does not occur):

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private AbstractB b;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractB {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected long id;   
}

@Entity
public class BImpl extends AbstractB {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private D d;
}

@Entity
public class D {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Size(min = 1)
    private Set<C> cs = new HashSet<C>();
}

@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
}
```

with an instance of A referencing a BImpl, which references a D, which in turn holds an instance of C in a set.

As you can see in the code, all references have orphanremoval set to true and CascadeType.ALL.

When I set the reference of A->AbstractB to null and merge back the instance of A, the following constraint violation occurs:

```
20:05:03,388 INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Fine]: 2012-04-13 20:05:03.388--ClientSession(2132156535)--Connection(1281180651)--Thread(Thread[http-0.0.0.0-443-2,5,jboss])--UPDATE A SET B_ID = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
20:05:03,388 INFO  [STDOUT]     bind => [null, 1]
20:05:03,390 INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Fine]: 2012-04-13 20:05:03.39--ClientSession(2132156535)--Connection(1281180651)--Thread(Thread[http-0.0.0.0-443-2,5,jboss])--DELETE FROM BIMPL WHERE (ID = ?)
20:05:03,390 INFO  [STDOUT]     bind => [2]
20:05:03,391 INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Fine]: 2012-04-13 20:05:03.391--ClientSession(2132156535)--Connection(1281180651)--Thread(Thread[http-0.0.0.0-443-2,5,jboss])--DELETE FROM ABSTRACTB WHERE (ID = ?)
20:05:03,391 INFO  [STDOUT]     bind => [2]
20:05:03,392 INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Fine]: 2012-04-13 20:05:03.392--ClientSession(2132156535)--Connection(1281180651)--Thread(Thread[http-0.0.0.0-443-2,5,jboss])--DELETE FROM C WHERE (ID = ?)
20:05:03,393 INFO  [STDOUT]     bind => [4]
20:05:03,393 INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Fine]: 2012-04-13 20:05:03.393--ClientSession(2132156535)--Thread(Thread[http-0.0.0.0-443-2,5,jboss])--SELECT 1
20:05:03,394 INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Warning]: 2012-04-13 20:05:03.394--UnitOfWork(2142376869)--Thread(Thread[http-0.0.0.0-443-2,5,jboss])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
20:05:03,394 INFO  [STDOUT] Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`D_C`, CONSTRAINT `FK_D_C_cs_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`cs_ID`) REFERENCES `C` (`ID`))
20:05:03,394 INFO  [STDOUT] Error Code: 1451
20:05:03,395 INFO  [STDOUT] Call: DELETE FROM C WHERE (ID = ?)
20:05:03,395 INFO  [STDOUT]     bind => [4]
```

Could anyone explain to me, why the D_C entry does not get deleted before the C instance?

Comment: Include the classes and mappings.  Setting logging on finest will also show you what is occurring.

Comment: Can you show your C->D mapping, and does it occur if you remove C directly?

Comment: Moved the classes from pastebin into posting.

Comment: When I store the constellation without A and delete the instance of BImpl directly, the error does not occur (deletion gets cascaded to D and C and D_C entry is deleted before the C instance). Same when BImpl is not inheriting from an abstract class and referenced directly by A.

Answer (score 1):

adding @CascadeOnDelete may solve your problem

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@CascadeOnDelete
@Size(min = 1)
public Set<TestChild> childrenSet = new HashSet<TestChild>();
```

see also: [EclipseLink DeleteCascade](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DeleteCascade)

HTH Danny

Comment: I tried about 5 different ways to solve this problem but I found, that using @CascadeOnDelete is the only useful soution.